# Huxtable: quick_xlsx does not display data after export

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I was successfully using `quick_xlsx` from `Huxtable` so far.
With the code below, when I opened the exported Excel file, it shows no data and the file started with column G, excluding the mtcars columns.

```
library(huxtable)
library(dplyr) 

data(mtcars)
car_ht <- as_hux(mtcars)
car_ht %<>% 
  set_all_padding(4) %>% 
  set_outer_padding(0) %>% 
  set_number_format(2) %>% 
  set_bold(1, everywhere) %>% 
  set_bottom_border(1, everywhere) %>% 
  set_width(0.4) %>% 
  set_caption("Mtcars") %>% 
  set_text_color(2:3, 1, "purple")

quick_xlsx(car_ht)
```

My sessionInfo() is

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.0    huxtable_5.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.0.4         Rcpp_1.0.4.6      pillar_1.4.4      compiler_4.0.0    remotes_2.1.1     prettyunits_1.1.1
 [7] tools_4.0.0       testthat_2.3.2    digest_0.6.25     pkgbuild_1.0.8    pkgload_1.1.0     memoise_1.1.0    
[13] lifecycle_0.2.0   tibble_3.0.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.6       openxlsx_4.1.5    cli_2.0.2        
[19] rstudioapi_0.11   commonmark_1.7    curl_4.3          xfun_0.15         withr_2.2.0       stringr_1.4.0    
[25] knitr_1.29        fs_1.4.1          generics_0.0.2    desc_1.2.0        vctrs_0.3.1       devtools_2.3.0   
[31] rprojroot_1.3-2   tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.1        R6_2.4.1          processx_3.4.2    fansi_0.4.1      
[37] sessioninfo_1.1.1 purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.4.3       magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.6.1     backports_1.1.8  
[43] ps_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1  stringi_1.4.6     crayon_1.3.4
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Gaston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package author here. The data is there, just hidden. Double click to the left of column G to expand the hidden columns A-F.

The bug is fixed in the github version of huxtable; you can download from there using `remotes::install_github("hughjonesd/huxtable")`, or just wait for the next version to come out.